# asp.net MVC3 create folder where application can write in

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, permissions

I need to create a folder to use for storing files within it, in a .Net MVC3 application, but I think the problem is common to all ASP.Net platform.
Problem is I can create the folder, but cannot write the files, because `System.UnauthorizedAccessException` occurred.
I also tryed givin extra permission to the user currently running the web app, but nothing changes.
This is my code so far:

```
if (!System.IO.Directory.Exists(fullPath))
{
    System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(fullPath);                    
    var user = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().User;
    var userName = user.Translate(typeof(System.Security.Principal.NTAccount));
    var dirInfo = new System.IO.DirectoryInfo(fullPath);
    var sec = dirInfo.GetAccessControl();                    
    sec.AddAccessRule(new System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule(userName,
                    System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemRights.Modify,
                    System.Security.AccessControl.AccessControlType.Allow)
                    );
    dirInfo.SetAccessControl(sec);                    
    System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(fullPath);                    
}
string fullPathFileName = System.IO.Path.Combine(fullPath, fileName);                
System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(fullPath, viaggio.Depliant.RawFile);
```

Too bad, last line of code always throw `System.UnauthorizedAccessException`.
I'm not impersonating user in my app, everything run under a predefined user.
What should I do to create a folder and assure that the application can also create files within it?

**Edited:**

I also tryed to save the files in the App_Data special folder, but I still got the `System.UnauthorizedAccessException` error. Somebody can tell me why is that happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hate to answer my own question when the problem is that stupid...
I'm just trying to save a file without a proper filename: you can see I'm using the `fullPath` variable both for creating the folder and for saving the file, instead of using the correctly created `fullPathFileName`.
Blame on me!

Answer (score 0):

Use App_Data folder, quote from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/06t2w7da%28v=vs.80%29.aspx :

To improve the security of the data used by your ASP.NET application, a new subfolder named App_Data has been added for ASP.NET applications. Files stored in the App_Data folder are not returned in response to direct HTTP requests, which makes the App_Data folder the recommended location for data stored with your application, including .mdf (SQL Server Express Edition), .mdb (Microsoft Access), or XML files. Note that when using the App_Data folder to store your application data, the identity of your application has read and write permissions to the App_Data folder.

Comment: I can't use the App_Data folder: the files that need to be uploaded are a lot, and could be big, and my requirements is to decouple application deployment from data-folder

Comment: Moreover, I tryed saving files even in the App_Data folder (to solve temporarly and go on with the development), but it doesn't work either... same error occured

Comment: can you check on server does IIS_IUSRS group have read / write access to the App_Data folder ?

Comment: Pretty strange that I can create and delete folder, but not create files, isn't it? I don't have a server at the time as I'm developing... so I'm using the VisualStudio 2010 integrated web server. Isn't there a way to check this programmatically?